# Search engine in javascript and django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Good day, I'm pretty new in django and python and newer still in javascript. And I'm mixing everyone! :(

Step to tell you that I'm making a website where a Manager enters the movements performed during a work day, separated into a list that also that list is divided into sublists.

On the website you are asked to enter the number of movements made in that workday (sublist), each of these movements correspond to different people who are discriminated against by an AUTOS AND JUDGE EJ: AUTOS: 251254 Court: PAZ 6.

In javascript I managed to enter the number of movements you want to load and automatically generate the amount of input and select that I need.

At that moment that the manager decided the number of movements that will be entered in that sublist, you must identify the client to whom the operation hosted in my database will be loaded, modeled in django.

Then in all the input you must enter the AUTOS number and in a SELECT - OPTION select the COURT to which that car belongs and bring me the name of the client lodged in the data base and the doubt that I have is how to make javascript communicate with django for each input - select that I have to perform the search of the client.

I leave the html and javascript code that I am using, I hope I could have been clear and help me to be able to continue, and if there is also a recommendation to do, I would be very grateful.
    {% extends 'base/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>datos</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block navbar %}
    {% endblock %}

<div class="container">


        <div class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="bs-component">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HOME</a>
                                </div>
                                <div  id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">VER ESTADO DE LISTAS<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"  aria-expanded="false">CUENTA CORRIENTE<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" onclick="pageTracker._link(this.href); return false;">FERNANDO DE LUCA - GESTOR</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Opciones<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Opciones Personales</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
                                        </ul>


                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <h1>NUEVO MOVIMIENTO GESTOR</h1>

    <form method="POST">

        {% csrf_token %}

<form>

Ingrese Detalle: <input size="30" type="text" name="detalle" id="detalle" value="" onkeyup="" />
Ingrese Honorarios: <input size="8" type="text" name="honorarios_total" id="honor" value="" onkeyup="" />
Ingrese Cantidad: <input size="5" type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="" onkeyup="crearCampos(this.value);" />




<p>


<div id="campos_dinamicos" class="form-group"></div>


<div id="campos_dinamicos_nuevo_gasto" class="form-group"></div>


</form>


<form method="POST">

<input size="5" type="button" name="agregar_gastos_varios" id="agregar_gastos_varios" value = "agregar_gastos_varios" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AgregarCampos(1);"/>


<input size="5" type="button" name="guardar_cambios" id="guardar_cambios" value = "guardar_cambios" class="btn btn-primary" />

<input size="5" type="button" name="cerrar_sublista" id="cerrar_sublista" value = "cerrar_sublista" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function AgregarCampos(cantidad){
var div = document.getElementById("campos_dinamicos_nuevo_gasto");
while(div.firstChild)div.removeChild(div.firstChild); // remover elementos;
    for(var i = 1, cantidad = Number(cantidad); i <= cantidad; i++){


    /*SALTO DE LINEA*/

    var salto_linea = document.createElement("P");

    /*DETALLE*/

    var dt_scliente = document.createElement("input");
    var dt_scliente_txt = document.createTextNode(" DETALLE: ");
    dt_scliente.setAttribute("name", "dt_scliente" + i);
    dt_scliente.setAttribute("size", "40");
    dt_scliente.className = "form-group";

    var importe_scliente = document.createElement("input");
    var importe_scliente_txt = document.createTextNode(" IMPORTE: ");
    importe_scliente.setAttribute("name", "importe_scliente" + i);
    importe_scliente.setAttribute("size", "5");
    importe_scliente.className = "form-group";



    div.appendChild(dt_scliente_txt) + div.appendChild(dt_scliente) + div.appendChild(importe_scliente_txt) + div.appendChild(importe_scliente);; 
    div.appendChild(salto);


    }

}


</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

function crearCampos(cantidad){
var div = document.getElementById("campos_dinamicos");
while(div.firstChild)div.removeChild(div.firstChild); // remover elementos;
    for(var i = 1, cantidad = Number(cantidad); i <= cantidad; i++){


    /*SALTO DE LINEA*/

    var salto = document.createElement("P");
    var total_h = document.getElementById("honor").value;


    var dividido = Math.round((parseInt(total_h) / parseInt(cantidad)))

    /*AUTOS*/
    var autos = document.createElement("input");
    var text_autos = document.createTextNode(" AUTOS N°: ");
    autos.setAttribute("name", "campo" + i);
    autos.setAttribute("size", "6");
    autos.className = "form-group";



     /*NOMBRE Y APELLIDO*/

    var nombre_apellido = document.createElement("input");
    var text_nombre_apellido = document.createTextNode(" CLIENTE: ");
    nombre_apellido.setAttribute("name", "nombre_apellido" + i);
    nombre_apellido.setAttribute("size", "15");
    nombre_apellido.className = "form-group";

         /*MOVILIDAD*/

    var movilidad = document.createElement("input");
    var text_movilidad = document.createTextNode(" MOVILIDAD.: ");
    movilidad.setAttribute("name", "movilidad" + i);
    movilidad.setAttribute("size", "5");
    movilidad.setAttribute("value", "0");
    movilidad.className = "form-group";

        /* FECHA */
    var fecha = document.createElement("input");
    var text_fecha = document.createTextNode(" FECHA: ");
    fecha.setAttribute("name", "movilidad" + i);
    fecha.setAttribute("type", "date");
    fecha.className = "form-group";



    var text_juzgado = document.createTextNode(" JUZGADO: ");
    var sel_juzgado = document.createElement("select");
    sel_juzgado.setAttribute("name", "juzgado" + i )
    var paz1 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz2 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz3 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz4 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz5 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz6 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz7 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz8 = document.createElement("option");
    var paz_lh = document.createElement("option");
    var paz_villanueva = document.createElement("option");
    var paz_lujan = document.createElement("option");
    var paz_sm = document.createElement("option");

    paz1.value = "1";
    paz1.text = "PAZ 1";

    paz2.value = "2";
    paz2.text = "PAZ 2";

    paz3.value = "3";
    paz3.text = "PAZ 3";

    paz4.value = "4";
    paz4.text = "PAZ 4";

    paz5.value = "5";
    paz5.text = "PAZ 5";

    paz6.value = "6";
    paz6.text = "PAZ 6";

    paz7.value = "7";
    paz7.text = "PAZ 7";


    paz8.value = "8";
    paz8.text = "PAZ 8";

    paz_lh.value = "9";
    paz_lh.text = "PAZ LAS HERAS";


    paz_villanueva.value = "10";
    paz_villanueva.text = "PAZ VILLANUEVA";


    paz_lujan.value = "11";
    paz_lujan.text = "PAZ LUJAN";

    paz_sm.value = "12";
    paz_sm.text = "PAZ SAN MARTIN";


    sel_juzgado.add(paz1, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz2, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz3, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz4, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz5, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz6, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz7, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz8, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz_lh, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz_villanueva, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz_lujan, null);
    sel_juzgado.add(paz_sm, null);





    div.appendChild(text_autos) + div.appendChild(autos) + div.appendChild(text_juzgado) + div.appendChild(sel_juzgado) + div.appendChild(text_nombre_apellido) + div.appendChild(nombre_apellido) + div.appendChild(text_movilidad) + div.appendChild(movilidad) + div.appendChild(text_fecha) + div.appendChild(fecha) 
    div.appendChild(salto)





    }



}



</script>





</body>
</html>



{% endblock %}
```

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: There is too much information here. You need to look at [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try